# Assembly. Why does GCC create extra instructions in the end of .text section?

Tags: windows, gcc, assembly, mingw, gnu-assembler

I'm learning GAS Assembler on Windows with MinGW-64 and I have a question about MinGW. Why does this compiler generate extra instructions in the end of .text section? I found some answers where people explain it is required for alignment reasons (the compiler does it to align next function by 8, 16 or 32 boundary). But I have the following simplest code

```
.text
.global _start

_start:
    xorq %rax, %rax
    retq
```

objdump shows this

```
test.exe:     file format pei-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000401000 <.text>:
  401000:       48 31 c0                xor    %rax,%rax
  401003:       c3                      retq
  401004:       90                      nop
  401005:       90                      nop
  401006:       90                      nop
  401007:       90                      nop
  401008:       90                      nop
  401009:       90                      nop
  40100a:       90                      nop
  40100b:       90                      nop
  40100c:       90                      nop
  40100d:       90                      nop
  40100e:       90                      nop
  40100f:       90                      nop
  401010:       ff                      (bad)
  401011:       ff                      (bad)
  401012:       ff                      (bad)
  401013:       ff                      (bad)
  401014:       ff                      (bad)
  401015:       ff                      (bad)
  401016:       ff                      (bad)
  401017:       ff 00                   incl   (%rax)
  401019:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  40101b:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  40101d:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  40101f:       00 ff                   add    %bh,%bh
  401021:       ff                      (bad)
  401022:       ff                      (bad)
  401023:       ff                      (bad)
  401024:       ff                      (bad)
  401025:       ff                      (bad)
  401026:       ff                      (bad)
  401027:       ff 00                   incl   (%rax)
  401029:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  40102b:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  40102d:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
        ...
```

If it is done for alignment reasons then I could just replace these extra instructions with any bytes except null-bytes and the program would execute properly, right? But when I replace all these extra bytes with, for example, 90 (nop instruction), the program stops to work correctly. Please explain me what's happening! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's possible those are relocation entries or some other metadata that the toolchain decided to fold into the text section. I would look at the file in some sort of PE viewer (e.g. PE Insider) and see if any of the data directories reference this data.

Comment: I did this and there are actually no any data directories that reference this data. But I tried again - removed all the data added by compiler and now it works... But if I create more complicated code like call winapi function MessageBoxA, it stops to work again...

Comment: At least my version of `objdump` shows those are associated with symbols `__CTOR_LIST__` and `__DTOR_LIST__` so those are some kind of entries for initialization and teardown. Couldn't find much detail about them so far.

Comment: Im not seeing it I cant repeat it I only get the two instructions both from an object and an executable, what version of binutils are you using and what are your command lines?

Comment: I have _GNU Binutils 2.28_ with _This assembler was configured for a target of 'x86_64-w64-mingw32'_ The `nop` padding is added by the assembler, the ctor/dtor by the linker. The [table is documented](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Output-Section-Keywords.html#index-CONSTRUCTORS) but I couldn't find a way to get rid of it.

Comment: The `nop`s out to `401010` are added by the linker for alignment of the `.text` section of whatever else got linked with your `start.o`.  Are you sure the rest is even part of the `.text` section of the final executable?  It can get mapped into memory as part of the page, even if it doesn't need to be there.  The `ff ff` and other bytes don't look like instructions at all.  Like maybe read-only constant data.

Comment: It is definitely not a part of any other sections because I have the .text section only (ok, it has .idata also, but it's locating much more below)